# PHP - Save crontab to the database

Tags: php, regex, cron

I have a variable that contains a list of 3 jobs that can be created in linux and I would like to save each line of work in my database:

```
$jobs = """
0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
"""
$array = explode(" ", $jobs);
$job = new Job;
$job->min = $array[0];
$job->hour = $array[1];
$job->day_month = $array[2];
$job->mes = $array[3];
$job->day_week = $array[4];
$job->command = "/bin/bash";
$job->save();
```

The problem that is occurring for me is that I am only managing to save the first line. The other lines are not saving, and I think it is because there is an enter between them.

Second question is how to use a regular expression to get only the command for my job `tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz / home /` that has spaces but I wanted to save the entire command in a table just called "command".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$array` will contain all words separated with a space.

```
[
 "0",
 "5",
 "*",
 "*",
 "1",
 "tar",
 "-zcf",
 "var/backups/home.tgz",
 "home\n0",
 "5",
 "*",
 "*",
 "1",
 ...
]
```

You need to split the lines and loop through them.

For the second question; use [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/array_slice) to get the remaining items from the array and then join them with [`implode`](https://www.php.net/implode).

```
$jobs = "
0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
";

$lines = explode("\n", trim($jobs));

foreach ($lines as $line) {
  $array = explode(" ", $line);
  $job = new Job;
  $job->min = $array[0];
  $job->hour = $array[1];
  $job->day_month = $array[2];
  $job->mes = $array[3];
  $job->day_week = $array[4];
  $job->command = implode(" ", array_slice($array, 5));
  $job->save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much brother, it helped me a lot.